# How to get date diffrence

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

I want to get difference: days, hour, min and seconds from these two dates

`2011-08-17 15:23:24` and `2011-08-11 14:00:11` in php.

Anyone can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php - Please check that the question hasn't been asked before.

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php or http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=php+difference+between+two+dates

Answer (score 0):

from example in [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
<?php 
    $date1 = new DateTime('2011-04-01'); 
    $date2 = new DateTime("now"); 
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2); 
    $years = $interval->format('%y'); 
    $months = $interval->format('%m'); 
    $days = $interval->format('%d'); 
    if($years!=0){ 
        $ago = $years.' year(s) ago'; 
    }else{ 
        $ago = ($months == 0 ? $days.' day(s) ago' : $months.' month(s) ago'); 
    } 
    echo $ago; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$d1=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','date1');
$d2=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s','date2');

$interval=$d1->diff($d2);
//use $interval->format(); here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1 = "2008-11-01 22:45:00"; 

$date2 = "2009-12-04 13:44:01"; 

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1)); 

$years   = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
$months  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24)); 
$days    = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

$hours   = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)/ (60*60)); 

$minuts  = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 

$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 - $hours*60*60 - $minuts*60)); 

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minuts\n, %d seconds\n", $years, $months, $days, $hours, $minuts, $seconds);
```

Answered by khaldonno on this link [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)